# In c, what is int(*)[]?

Tags: c

In some c code I inherited, I have seen the following

```
int (*b)[] = (int(*)[])a;
```

What is int(*)[] and how is this different than int**?

Comment: [www.cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*b%29%5B%5D)

Comment: 1) `int (*b)[]` [declares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-declarations-and-definitions?view=msvc-170) "b" as a pointer to an array of int. 2) `(int(*)[])` [casts](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) "a" to a point to an array of int.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [The ``Clockwise/Spiral Rule''](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html),

`int(*)[]` is a pointer to an array of int.

```
int(*)[]       int[]
+---------+    +---------+
|      ------->|         |
+---------+    +---------+
               :         :
```

`int**` is a pointer to a pointer to an int.

```
int**          int*           int
+---------+    +---------+    +---------+
|      ------->|      ------->|         |
+---------+    +---------+    +---------+
               :?        :?   :?        :?
```

As you can see, `int(*)[]` is closer to `int*` than to `int**`.

```
int*           int
+---------+    +---------+
|      ------->|         |
+---------+    +---------+
               :?        :?
```

Comment: Understood, but in use, if I had `int **c = (int**)a;`, would (*b)[1] == (*c)[1] or does this have no common meaning?

Comment: That would make no sense. And it would be undefined behaviour. You'd be comparing the int* after the int* at *c with the int after the int at *b. You might not even be comparing the same locations. (`&(*b)[1])` is commonly different than `&((*c)[1])`.)

Answer (score 1):

All of these have distinctively different meanings:

- `int*` = pointer to `int`
- `int[]` = array of int, with incomplete type since the size is missing.
- `int**` = pointer to pointer to `int`.
- `int(*)[]` = pointer to (incomplete) array of int

Notably an `int**`, pointer to pointer to `int`, *cannot* be assigned to point at an array, nor to an array of arrays. It has nothing to do with arrays! With one special exception: it can be assigned to point at the first element in an array of `int*`, that is an array of type `int* arr[]`. We may then write `int** ptr = arr;` in that special case and only then.

Most of the misconception regarding `int**` originates from the misconception that `int**` together with malloc could be used to allocate a 2D array, which was never the case, see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Regarding `int(*)[]` it's a handy type in some cases, since an array with no size (incomplete type) is compatible with an array of fixed size (through a special rule called "composite type"). So we can use a `int(*)[]` to point at any `int` array type no matter size. Or use it to create a macro to check if something is an array: `#define IS_INT_ARRAY(x) _Generic(&(x), int(*)[]: puts(#x " is an int array"))`